# Lumen gives NotFoundHttpException in RoutesRequests.php without public/index.php

Tags: apache, laravel, lumen

The Lumen installation in my server is giving NotFoundHttpException when accessing without public/index.php.

Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myapi/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/myapi>
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Directory structure:

```
> var/www/html
> ------------/myapi/ (lumen application)
> ------------/myapi/public/
```

index.php in var/www/html/myapi/public

```
$app->run($app->make('request'));
```

NotFoundHttpException:

1. in RoutesRequests.php line 461
2. at Application->handleDispatcherResponse(array('0')) in RoutesRequests.php line 398
3. at Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns{closure}() in RoutesRequests.php line 650
4. at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array(), object(Closure)) in RoutesRequests.php line 400
5. at Application->dispatch(object(Request)) in RoutesRequests.php line 341
6. at Application->run(object(Request)) in index.php line 30

Comment: Most likely you don't have a route for your index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NotFoundHttpException** is given when your request is not listed in `route.php`

```
$app->get('request', function() {
return view('your view file');
});
```

Comment: I do have the request listed in /var/www/html/myapi/routes/web.php in lumen 5.3. \n `$app->get('/hello', function () use ($app) {
    return "Hello Universe";`
});

Comment: not `web.php`...`route.php` is located inside **app/html** folder.

Comment: Thanks for your response Sachith. Lumen 5.3 seems to have removed the route.php and replaced with web.php in the 'routes' folder.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved by changing the

```
$app->run();
```

in `/public/index.php` to

```
$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();
$app->run($request);
```